# PowerShell Select weirdness

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have two select statements here. The "headings" from the first (message, username,timegenerated) are being used for the second (username,timegenerated).

Please look at the echo statement to see that the tables\outputs are being merged into one.

Can anyone explain why?

This needs to be run in a ps1 script to see the weirdness:

```
$before = get-date
$after = (get-date).AddDays(-1)

$a = Get-EventLog System -Before $before -After $after | ? {$_.Message -like "*start*"}

$a | select message, username,timegenerated

echo "----going through security----" 

$b = Get-Eventlog security -Before $before -After $after |?{$_.category -match "Logon/Logoff" } 

$b | select username,timegenerated
```

The output is this:

```
Message                                                UserName                                               TimeGenerated
-------                                                --------                                               -------------
The Engine service was successfully sent a star...     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                    22/09/2011 09:32:09
The Engine service was successfully sent a star...     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                    21/09/2011 16:03:57
The Licensing Service service was successfu...         DOMAIN\username                                        21/09/2011 15:58:12
----going through security----
                                                       DOMAIN\9876ABC$                                        22/09/2011 14:05:41
                                                       DOMAIN\9876ABC$                                        22/09/2011 14:04:58
                                                       DOMAIN\9876ABC$                                        22/09/2011 14:03:40
                                                       DOMAIN\9876ABC$                                        22/09/2011 14:02:57
                                                       NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE                             22/09/2011 14:01:59
```

Comment: To be honest I can't tell what the select is doing at all since you are not showing the field that you are filtering on in the example output.

Comment: @EBGree - Run the code from a ps1 file in your console to see the strange behavior.

Comment: @EBGreen that's why it's weird - i am showing the output! I'll edit it to include Christian's comment though as it's not clear. Thanks Christian :-)

Comment: What do you mean by 'using values from the first'? Which values? The UserNames are different for the two selects you've shown. They've been formatted into one table but I can't see any similarities?

Comment: @MrKWatkins as you say the tables have been merged into on table. The headings for the table (what I've called values) are from the first select statement.

Comment: the second select-object doesn't show names for columns but being $a and $b of same type mantains only the name of column of first select-object

Comment: No, actually I do not. I am on a fresh machine where permissions are not set properly yet, so I don't have rights to run the second portion of the code. Posting the information also means that every person that is interested in helping you doesn't have to do more work just to help you out.

Comment: I do understand the question more completely now that you have explained that by 'values' you meant column headers.

Comment: @EBGreen: I think is only a problem of how is formatted the Question (more line enter than the real output in powershell) but the question is clear!

Comment: @EBGreen Sorry mate but i think you're missing the point. the information is posted. The second output is being merged into the first - hence why it looks like only the first is being outputted. And I've seen you around these and other boards enough to know you can see what a select statement should do. I'll amend my question though.

Comment: Yes, I did misunderstand the question initially. generally speaking 'values' means the content of the data not the headers. I still can't reproduce it or explain it, but at least I understand it now.

Comment: It's possible to reproduce the issue with `$a = gps|select -First 10;$a|select name;$a|select ws`. I found that adding `Format-*` statements to the end of each pipe will display the columns correctly: `$a = gps|select -First 10;$a|select name|ft;$a|select ws|ft`

Comment: Placing the `Format-Table` at the end of the second pipeline causes an error to be thrown, but I'm not sure why. `$a = gps|select -First 10; $a|select name; $a|select ws|ft`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a formatting issue, the following seems to work as expected though:

```
$before = get-date
$after = (get-date).AddDays(-1)

$a = Get-EventLog System -Before $before -After $after | ? {$_.Message -like "*start*"}

$a | select message, username,timegenerated | format-table -force

echo "----going through security----" 

$b = Get-Eventlog security -Before $before -After $after |?{$_.category -match "Logon/Logoff" } 

$b | select username,timegenerated | format-table -force
```

Additionally, this definitely looks like a bug concerning the output of multiple custom psobjects (created above as a result of doing the selects).

The following code explicitly creates a separate PSObject for each query result and returns the same results as your code (i.e. only one set of headings):

```
$before = get-date
$after = (get-date).AddDays(-1)

$a = Get-EventLog System -Before $before -After $after | ? {$_.Message -like "*start*"}
$a = $a | `
    % {New-Object PSObject -Property `
        @{Message = $_.message; Username = $_.username; Timegenerated = $_.timegenerated}
    }
$a

echo "----going through security----" 

$b = Get-Eventlog security -Before $before -After $after |?{$_.category -match "Logon/Logoff" } 
$b = $b | `
    % {New-Object PSObject -Property `
        @{Username = $_.username; Timegenerated = $_.timegenerated}
    }
$b
```

Run this in PS_ISE and execute:

```
$a | gm
$b | gm
```

You can see that they are distinct objects with different properties.  Things get even weirder if you don't use the same key names between objects; look at the results returned if we change:

```
$b = $b | `
    % {New-Object PSObject -Property `
        @{Username = $_.username; Timegenerated = $_.timegenerated}
    }
```

to:

```
$b = $b | `
    % {New-Object PSObject -Property `
        @{UsernameB = $_.username; TimegeneratedB = $_.timegenerated}
    }
```

For those with no will to run this, it returns whitespace where the security result set should be.  Running Get-Member again shows two custom objects, each with it's own properties.

It's probably worth logging this with Microsoft Connect although it looks like PSCustomObjects *might* be getting an overhaul in v3, see [here](http://www.jonathanmedd.net/2011/09/powershell-v3-creating-objects-with-pscustomobject-its-fast.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what do you mean by formatting issue. I'm really interested to understand the cause.

Answer (score 1):

This is a function of PowerShell's console output. When you output the first set of objects, you set the format for all subsequent objects. Everything following will be presented as a continuous stream of objects within the same table and publishing the same properties.

If you emit $a in one run and $b in a completely different run, you'll see you've really got two distinct sets of objects. You're just seeing a console formatting issue here.